# fadeOut the child then animate the height of the div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout

I'm trying to make the child of a div fade out and then animate the height of the div itself, i tried in jsFiddle, but it doesn't work, and there appear some strange lines... Can anyone help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/kPq6J/7/

Comment: Just noticed that your bug relates to Chrome, you should tag your question and provide the info accordingly. FF doesn't have that bug.

Comment: Removing the CSS reset stylesheet from the fiddle seems to solve it for Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/kPq6J/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is captured in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f3Lpv/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggleid").click(function() {
        var child = $("#child");

        if(child.is(":visible")) {
            child.fadeTo(500, 0.0, function() {
                child.slideUp();
            });
            $("#toggleid").text("Show");
        } else {
            child.slideDown(function() {
                child.fadeTo(500, 1.0);                        
            });
            $("#toggleid").text("Hide");
        }
    });
});​
```

In order to avoid artifact issues in chrome, you may want to ensure that your css sets the bottom padding to 1px.  Not sure if this is necessary always or just in jsFiddle:

```
body { 
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

See also this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/f3Lpv/2/) for a slightly different animation technique on the fadein.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
$(function() {
    $("#toggleid").click(function(e) {
        var mh = $("#mother").height(),
            ch = $("#child").outerHeight();
        $("#mother").height(mh);
        if ($("#child").is(":visible")) {
            $("#child").fadeOut(500, function(e) {
                $("#mother").animate({ height: mh-ch });
                $("#toggleid").text("Show");
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#mother").animate({ height: mh+ch }, function(e) {
                $("#child").fadeIn(500);
                $("#toggleid").text("Hide");
            });
        };
    });
});
```

**However!** if you want it to be more dynamic you might consider something more like:

```
$(function() {
    $(".toggleClass").live("click", function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $mother = $this.parent(),
            $child = $this.siblings("div"), // maybe replace with Css Class ".child"
            mh = $mother.height(),
            ch = $child.outerHeight();
        $mother.height(mh);
        if ($child.is(":visible")) {
            $child.fadeOut(500, function(e) {
                $mother.animate({ height: mh-ch });
                $this.text("Show");
            });
        }
        else {
            $mother.animate({ height: mh+ch }, function(e) {
                $child.fadeIn(500);
                $this.text("Hide");
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Steve Campbell's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835180/1092815), I updated the jsfiddle use jquery plugin instead.

usage: `child.smoothFadeIn();` and `child.smoothFadeOut();`

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.smoothFadeOut = function () {
        var selector = this;
        selector.slideDown(function () {
            selector.fadeTo(500, 1.0);
        });
    };

    $.fn.smoothFadeIn = function () {
        var selector = this;
        selector.fadeTo(500, 0.0, function () {
            selector.slideUp();
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

[jsFiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/f3Lpv/3/)